# Show a shorter title in the bottom part of the presentation

Tags: beamer, titles

How can I show a shorter title so it doesn't get cut, this is an example of my problem.

In the bottom part the title is cut before finishing so i want to show something shorter just **[Lorem Ipsum and other stuff]** and not the full title. I am new to using beamer and i have been in latex just a couple months, any help would be appreciated, thanks.
[image: The problem]

Comment: In the future, it's always a good idea to provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It helps getting the process started of working towards a solution, and it's much quicker than trying to come up with something from scratch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to use

```
\title[<short title>]{<title>}
```

From the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (section **10.1 Adding a Title Page**):

> ```
> \title[<short title>]{<title>}
> ```
>
> The `<short title>` is used in headlines and footlines. Inside the `<title>` line breaks can be inserted using the double-backslash command.